# dosbox debugging while mouse loop is active

Tags: debugging, dosbox

I'm creating an assembly project using dosbox and I have some sort of heisenbug when I use the mouse, I'm using turbo debugger for debugging but I can't use the mouse and look in the cpu at the same time because using the mouse includes an in infinite loop.
My question is: is there any way in which I can use the mouse to create the bug and then look at the cpu/memory to see what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a way to exit the loop, I ran the program from the debugger and when i wanted to look at the cpu I right-clicked to exit the loop.